# Why doesn't ?NumericQ work in NDSolve with two variable?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the following set of differential eqiations

$\qquad y''(x) + a\,\sin(x) z(x) = 0 \quad z''(x) + a\,z(x) y(x) = 0$

where $a$ is a parameter. I want to get a solution for many values ofd $a$, so I constructed something like the following (I didn't want to use `ParametricNDSolve` as the actual equation I need to solve is stiff as well as I need to solve some algebraic equation in terms of solutions to find out a specific $a$)

```
{y1[a_?NumericQ], z1[a_?NumericQ]} := 
  {y1[a], 
   z1[a]} = {y, z} /. 
     NDSolve[
       {y''[x] + a*Sin[x] z[x] == 0, z''[x] + a*z[x] 
        y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, y'[0] == -0.1, z'[0] == 0.05}, 
       {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}] // First
```

I have used these type of functionalized constructs for single differential equation, but in this case of system of equations the following error is showing

> SetDelayed::shape: Lists {y1[a_?NumericQ],z1[a_?NumericQ]} and {y1[a],z1[a]}=First[{y,z}/. NDSolve[{(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]+Times[<<3>>]==0,(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]+Times[<<3>>]==0,y[0]==0,z[0]==0,(y^[Prime])[0]==-0.1,(z^[Prime])[0]==0.05},{y,z},{x,0,10}]] are not the same shape. >>

How can I solve the problem? Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with `ParametricNDSolveValue`?

Comment: The original equation which I want to solve is of three variables besides it is a stiff equation, i.e., I need to use `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`.

Comment: I am not sure about the `//` issue, using `First[]` also yields the same error.

Comment: I was wrong about `First`.  The problem is that there are in fact two separate definitions, and they must be independent.  I would have *a single* function that returns two values, or similar, if I really wanted memoization.

Comment: Does `ParametricNDSolveValue` not work with `"StiffnessSwitching"`?  I just tried it and it worked fine.  Furthermore, it seems to support solution caching too, which means that you do not need memoization.

Comment: I will try it in my original problem, However, I need to use the solution to solve some algebraic equation to find the correct value of the parameter. I have no idea how to proceed in this case!

Comment: It seems.FindRoot works in this case but NSolve doesn't!

Comment: That still does not explain why you can't use ParametricNDSolveValue. Time for a rethink and a clean start?

Comment: Because NSolve works with formulas, not numerical black boxes.

Comment: I think you are right ParametricNDSolve will work, but I would be happy if functionalized constructs could also work. You see 'the more the merrier'!

Comment: Since the two functions from the solution of a single system, and a single computation, they should be returned by a single function.   That will solve your problem

Comment: Can you please show me a way of implementing the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an expression of the form

```
{a, b} := Set[...]
```

Assigning multiple values simultaneously requires lists of the same shape to be explicitly present on both sides of the `:=`, i.e. `{a,b} = {c,d}`.  This is not the case here, hence the error.

You can't have an explicit list on the RHS because you use a single computation to get both functions, not two computations.

If you want to avoid `ParametricNDSolveValue`, define a *single* function instead, which returns *two* interpolating functions.

```
sol[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + a*Sin[x] z[x] == 0, z''[x] + a*z[x] y[x] == 0,
    y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, y'[0] == -0.1, z'[0] == 0.05}, {y, z}, {x, 
   0, 10}]

funs = sol[1]

Through[funs[1]]
(* {-0.103905, 0.0504225} *)
```

That said, I strongly suggest just using [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html), which was made exactly for this purpose.

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + a*Sin[x] z[x] == 0, 
   z''[x] + a*z[x] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, y'[0] == -0.1, 
   z'[0] == 0.05}, {y, z}, {x, 0, 10}, a]
```

Now `psol[1]` returns the same thing as `sol[1]`.

`ParametricNDSolveValue` also gives you caching for free, so you do not have to try to implement your own memoization.  See the `"ParametricCaching"` option.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.